# select query and while loop doesn't return all rows correctly

Tags: php, mysql, select, while-loop

can you explain me why when i try this query it returns to me only half of rows?

For example, if $records is made by 4 values it only get row 1 and 3 from DB.

What's wrong?

```
                $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREF."books WHERE book_id IN ('".$records."')");
                while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    global $book_id, $book_title, $book_description, $book_author_id, $book_author_name, $book_author_surname;
                    $book_id=$fetch['book_id'];
                    $book_title=$fetch['book_title'];
                    $book_description=$fetch['book_description'];
                    $book_author_id=$fetch['book_author_id'];
                    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREF."profiles WHERE user_id='".$book_author_id."'");
                    $fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                    $book_author_name=$fetch['user_name'];
                    $book_author_surname=$fetch['user_surname'];
                    getModule('htmlmodule...');
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you overwriting your $fetch variable in the loop? Maybe try:

```
$fetch2=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

Or, even better, use a join in your SQL:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREF."books LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREF."profiles ON book_author_id = user_id WHERE book_id IN ('".$records."')");
```

Then just get everything you want out of that single query.

Answer (score 0):

MY DO WHILE

```
mysql_select_db($database_lolx, $lolx);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM person";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $lolx) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>emal</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['emal']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</table>
```